# Is there a framework/library/... that supplies web UI components for table/record navigation and filtering?

Tags: web-apps, java

Like the desktop DBMSs [Access](http://www.baycongroup.com/access2007/06_access.html) and [Libre-/OpenOffice Base](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Form_Navigation_Bar) supply them for their forms:

[image: https://www.baycongroup.com/access2007/images/06_NavigationPane.gif]

*[Tags that do not exist and which I'm not allowed to add with less than 300 reps:]*

<kbd>vaadin</kbd> <kbd>hibernate</kbd>

Comment: 1) I assume it doesn’t *have* to work with Vaadin and (not *or*) Hibernate, correct? If it doesn’t have to, the tags should not be added. If it does have to, you should explicitly note this in your question. 2) The solution has to be in Java? Same thing here: if not, the [tag:java] tag should not be added.

Answer (score 2):

## Vaadin Grid

[Vaadin Grid](https://vaadin.com/grid) is a commercial product that provides *very* advanced data grid features to a web app. Originally available for the [Vaadin Java-based server-side framework](https://vaadin.com/framework), now also available as a [Web Component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Components) (GWT Polymer widget) with a JavaScript API for client-side use.

Vaadin grid has sophisticated support for lazy-loading and filtering of data. So no need for the paging feature shown in the Question.

See [this live demo](http://demo.vaadin.com/commit-browser/) or these other [live demos of the Vaadin Grid](http://vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/grids-and-trees/grid) in action.

Answer (score 1):

A Grid control like Syncfusion [ejGrid](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/grid/filtering/filteringmenu) can be used to display tables that allow for record navigation and filtering.

[image: Syncfusion ejGrid]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but a grid doesn't help me atm. I need just a navigation/filtering component for a "freestyle" page like the forms in the mentioned desktop DBMSs.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion provides a pager control [ejPager](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/bootstrap/pager/defaultfunctionalities).
Sample that mimics the Access pager [link](http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/xixsno2z)

[image: Syncfusion Pager]

The entire product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense?refer=srecs39882) program if you qualify (less than 1 million USD in revenue).

Note: I work for Syncfusion.